# How to prevent text going over button

Tags: html, css

I have a box with an image at the right-side and text at the left-side. The box should have a white background. At smaller screens the text goes below the image which is good.

A few px above the bottom of the box I want to have a button.
Think I should do that by using position relative for the box and position absolute for the button.

The CSS and HTML code is

```css
.box {
  background: white;
  float: right;
  position: relative
}

.space {
  padding: 15px;
}

.button {
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 40px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img class="box" src="https://d2f0ora2gkri0g.cloudfront.net/e4/16/e4164876-1967-4303-9a57-aae00eb2b22b.png" alt="oproeien" style="margin-right:0px; margin-left:0px">
  <h2 class="space">Amsterdam</h2>
  <p class="space">Amsterdam is de (titulaire) hoofdstad en naar inwonertal de grooteeuw tot stadsuitbreidingen, waaronder de laatste grachten van de fortificatie die nu als grachtengordel bekend is en in 2010 is toegevoegd aan de UNESCO-Werelderfgoedlijst.</p>
  <a class="button" href="https://www.buienradar.nl">Slecht weer</a>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Problem is that on smaller screen the text is displayed over the button. Another issue is that padding of the text does not prevent it getting connected to image (laptop/desktop). I do not want to add margin-left to picture because I want the line `<hr>`to be connected to the image.

Comment: From class `.button`, remove `position:absolute;`

Answer (score 0):

The button is over the text because you have used `position:absolute` to the button.

Set `position:relative` and `bottom:auto` in the smaller screen using media query rule...

Also using `vertical-align: middle;` in the `absolute` positioned elements will do nothing...so better to remove it

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.box {
  background: white;
  float: right;
  position: relative
}

.space {
  padding: 15px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 40px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
  .button {
    position: relative;
    bottom: auto;
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img class="box" src="https://d2f0ora2gkri0g.cloudfront.net/e4/16/e4164876-1967-4303-9a57-aae00eb2b22b.png" alt="oproeien" style="margin-right:0px; margin-left:0px">
  <h2 class="space">Amsterdam</h2>
  <p class="space">Amsterdam is de (titulaire) hoofdstad en naar inwonertal de grooteeuw tot stadsuitbreidingen, waaronder de laatste grachten van de fortificatie die nu als grachtengordel bekend is en in 2010 is toegevoegd aan de UNESCO-Werelderfgoedlijst.</p>
  <a class="button" href="https://www.buienradar.nl">Slecht weer</a>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!,  that works fine.  I also want the `<hr>` at some position below the button, but as soon as I use "position"  the `<hr>` is not displayed anymore.

Comment: I meant,  at laptop the '<hr>' is direct after the text.  I want it below the button.

Comment: @Jorke use `hr` outside of the `box` class

Comment: @Bhwan,  yes but then it is also below the image.  I just want the line about 20px above the bottom of the left part.  So half way between the button and the bottom of the box. (desktop/laptop).   At small screens the line may dissappear.

Comment: @Jorke its not clear what you are looking for and also it's not the part of your question...So it will be good if you post another question for this with working example...

Comment: @Bhwan, OK, I will do that.  thank you for your support/help , I'm a bit new in this world of code and at stackoverflow.